# Multiple glBufferData call, too many VBO

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-ndk

I’m working on Android OpenGL ES 1.1 game, and looking for help in fixing bugs that makes apps randomly (quite often) crash. 
App has its origins in iOS, so it used glMapBufferOES to fill vertex array and then draw. As it is only OpenGL extension I decided to remove it and continously upload data using glBufferData.

Before calling that method i setup vertex buffer with glGenBuffer and glBindBuffer. There we find a first problem. Before uploading vertices i always clear vbo and generate new with glGenBuffers( 1, &vertexVBO );, but after checking its size (vertexVBO) it keeps incrementing  1, 2, 3, 4 etc after every upload. After some time vertex buffer has size 150 instead of 1.

It seems like it causes heap memory corruption. How can I prevent this overflow and keep vertexVBO size always 1? Should I even use VBO if I don’t want to use glMapBufferOES?

Comment: The _name_ of a buffer object isn't its _size_. The GL is free to choose any name it likes. However, from your post, it is unlcear if you actually destroy the old buffer object or not. Whay do you mean by " i always clear vbo"?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Before changes mentioned above, I generated buffers with glGenBuffer, alocated empty buffer storage once with glBufferData and then used glMapBufferOES to fill data. Now I removed glMapBufferOES and I'm uploading vertex data multiple times using glBufferData. Before that I use glDeleteBuffer and then glGenBuffer. I'm wondering if it can cause memory corruption. Can I use glBufferData multiple times before glDrawArrays?

Comment: You can use glBufferData how often you want. I don't really get the point of the question, though.

Comment: @derhass I understands you now as it seems not to be the problem with glBufferData. App crashes randomly, most often after executing Java's onTouchEvent and sending it to JNI. App updates and render on thread created via JNi, but touch events comes from main thread. I think it might cause problems (drawing dispatched from different thread). Do you guys have any thoughts how to prevent it or link to a tutorial how to set it up correctly?